# Finding Bracketed Elements in a String following Tokens

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Given a StringBuilder of a text file with formatting A [1, 2, 3, 4] B [5, 6, 7, 8] C [9, 10]

I need to create a method so that when given the text file's name, and a token to search
i.e. "StringBuilder ex.txt" and "A", respectively,it will return a list with elements
1, 2, 3, and 4.

Regex is unfamiliar to me, so I'd like to use scanner if possible.
To do this, I learned that it's necessary to first use .toString on the Stringbuilder file.

So what I have so far is

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileContent.toString())
```

I understand the use of split to take out commas.  I don't need a full solution, but any help in what I should do first (would it be wise to use an array, then look for the index of tokens, or is there a simpler method of which I am unaware?) would help.

new code (for strings instad of numbers in brackets):

```
    public List<String> getPhrases(StringBuilder fileContent, String token) {
      StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(fileContent.toString()));
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
        if (tokenizer.sval.equals(token)) {
          tokenizer.nextToken();  // '[' 
          do {
            tokenizer.nextToken();  // go to the number
            list.append(String.valueOf(tokenizer.nval));
          } while (tokenizer.nextToken() == ',');
          break;
        }
      } 
      return list;
    }
```

I have an error of incompatibility between types with append.  Can someone mend this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use StreamTokenizer.

```
static List<Double> getElements(String fileContent, String token) {
  StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(fileContent));
  List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
  while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
    if (tokenizer.sval.equals(token)) {
      tokenizer.nextToken();  // '[' 
      do {
        tokenizer.nextToken();  // go to the number
        list.append(tokenizer.nval);
      } while (tokenizer.nextToken() == ',');
      break;
    }
  } 
  return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  In the particular program I'm working with, the list is actually a list of strings.  In modifying the code provided to fit the program, I'm presented with the error of list.append not working on strings.  What would you suggest doing?

Comment: Change `List<Double>` to `List<String>`

Comment: thanks, I actually tried that already and for some reason it doesn't work.  I've also tried combinations of applying toString to tokenizer.nval, and changing nval to sval.  I've updated the code above to match the current version being used.

Comment: Changing to `list.append(tokenizer.sval);` should do the job. Are the strings quoted?

Answer (score 0):

```
static List<Double> getList(String content, String name) {
    int namePos = content.indexOf(name);

    // return null if name not found
    if(namePos < 0) return null;

    // starting from namePos, find start and end of array
    int start = content.indexOf("[", namePos),
          end = content.indexOf("]", namePos);

    // get substring between "[" and "]", and split data by ","
    String[] strArray = content.substring(start + 1, end).split(",")

    List<Double> l = new ArrayList<Double>(strArray.length);

    // convert to Double
    for(String str : strArray)
        l.add(Double.parseDouble(str));

    return l;
}

public static void main(String...strings){
    // returns [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
    System.out.print(getList("A [1, 2, 3, 4] B [5, 6, 7, 8] C [9, 10]", "A"));
}
```